# Recursively calculating ratios between parents and children in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I looked around for a solution to this to the best of my ability. The closest I was able to find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521390/getting-all-descendants-of-a-parent-from-a-pandas-dataframe-parent-child-table), but it's not really what I'm looking for.

I am trying to model the relationship between a value and its parent's value. Specifically trying to calculate a ratio. I would also like to keep track of the level of lineage, like how many children deep is this item?

For example, I would like to input a pandas df that looks like this:

```
id  parent_id   score
1   0           50
2   1           40
3   1           30
4   2           20
5   4           10
```

and get this:

```
id  parent_id   score   parent_child_ratio  level
1   0           50      NA                  1
2   1           40      1.25                2
3   1           30      1.67                2
4   2           20      2                   3
5   4           10      2                   4
```

So for every row, we go find the score of its parent and then calculate (parent_score/child_score) and make that the value of a new column. And then some sort of counting solution add on the child level.

This has been stumping me for a while, any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is just merges:

```
with_parent = pd.merge(df, df, left_on='parent_id', right_on='id', how='left')
with_parent['child_parent_ratio'] = with_parent.score_y /     with_parent.score_x 
with_parent = with_parent.rename(columns={'id_x': 'id', 'parent_id_x': 'parent_id', 'score_x': 'score'})[['id', 'parent_id', 'score', 'child_parent_ratio']]
>>> with_parent
id  parent_id   score   child_parent_ratio
0   1   0   50  NaN
1   2   1   40  1.250000
2   3   1   30  1.666667
3   4   2   20  2.000000
4   5   4   10  2.000000
```

For the second part you can run [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). This creates a forest, and the level is the distance from the roots, as in:

[image]

E.g., using [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(set(with_parent['id'].unique()).union(set(with_parent.parent_id.unique())))
G.add_edges_from([(int(r[1]['parent_id']), int(r[1]['id'])) for r in with_parent.iterrows()])
with_parent['level'] = with_parent['id'].map(nx.shortest_path_length(G, 0))
>>> with_parent
    id  parent_id   score   child_parent_ratio  level
0   1   0   50  NaN         1
1   2   1   40  1.250000    2
2   3   1   30  1.666667    2
3   4   2   20  2.000000    3
4   5   4   10  2.000000    4
```

Comment: Nice answer, super :)

Comment: Thank you, jezrael!

Comment: @AmiTavory what should I do if there is more than one super-parent? In this example, 0 is the parent of all, but in my use case there are multiple family trees. I tried removing the source arg for nx.shortest_path_length but because that returns a dict of dicts, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @AdhiR. Assuming the number of those is low, I'd suggest finding the ids that have no parents, running shortest length from each one, and discarding unreachables from them. If the nodes form not a forest but a DAG, then the problem is more complicated, and topological sort is needed. If this is the case, I suggest you open a question just about that issue (w/o a focus on Pandas at all), and tag it also as graph theory. If you do so, feel free to ping here, and I'll be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: @AmiTavory I am definitely a novice with graph theory so please bear with me, haha. What I am modeling is actually an online forum, with posts and comments and replies to those comments. So, if by forest you mean many trees, that's what it is I think. (And then each individual tree is technically a DAG, correct?) So, I actually know by the characteristic of the id which are top level and which are children. The thing is, there are a lot of these comments and posts. I will try your first suggested strategy on a small sunset and see what I can do, thank you.

Comment: @AdhiR. You're correct. I also should have written "non-tree DAG" instead of "DAG" in the above (a tree is a DAG). In general, I think your problem is pretty simple Pandas-wise, but has graph theory questions. Again, I suggest asking a new question with your above comment: I am modeling an online forum, here is the dataframe, I'd like to find the levels, what is the best way? If you ping me here, I'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: Hi Ami, I got back from a long vacation shortly after this discussion and started working on this again. You were right about how to deal with the forest. All it took was using a function that by default disregards unreachables (nx.single_source_shortest_path_length), looping through unique super-parents, then updating that data into another dict.

Then I just mapped the dict to the original df. This way I didn't have to deal with any nested dict stuff like you did. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank` function

```
df = df.merge(df.drop('parent_id', axis=1).rename(index=str, columns={'id' :'parent_id', 'score':'score_p'}), on='parent_id', how='left')
df['Ratio'] = df['score_p']/df['score']
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'parent_id'])
df['level'] = df.parent_id.rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using pandas apply method:

```
def parent_child_ratio(row):
    if row['parent_id'] != 0:
        return df.loc[row['parent_id']]['score'] / row['score']

df['parent_child_ratio'] = df.apply(parent_child_ratio, axis=1)


1   0   50  NaN
2   1   40  1.250000
3   1   30  1.666667
4   2   20  2.000000
5   4   10  2.000000
```

as for a level column, shouldn't it just be `parent_id + 1`?