# More elegant way to recursively iterate to create a staff listing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a better way to create a listing of employees that belong to a single leaders' organization when I only have a listing of employees and their managers?

My current approach is to find in FULL (dataframe with all employees and their managers) the employees who report to that executive (TEMP1), append TEMP1 to a running list (SMITH_STAFF), then iterate over TEMP1 to find their direct reports in FULL (saved to TEMP2), save TEMP2 to SMITH_STAFF, etc.

My approach works, but it is quite kooky.  There has to be a better way, but all my searches and trying for loops, etc. did not work.  I can't find a more elegant way.

The FULL dataframe contains 'Email Address' and 'Manager Email Address' for all employees.  Example:

Email Address   Mgr Email Address
employee1       johnsmith
employee2       employee1
employee3       employee2
employee4       tomhamks

```
SMITH_STAFF = pd.DataFrame()
TEMP1 = FULL.loc[FULL['Mgr Email Address']=="johnsmith@company.com"]
SMITH_STAFF = SMITH_STAFF.append(TEMP1)

TEMP2 = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in TEMP1.iterrows():
    TEMP2 = TEMP2.append(FULL.loc[FULL['Mgr Email Address']==row["Email 
Address"]])
SMITH_STAFF = SMITH_STAFF.append(TEMP2)

TEMP3 = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in TEMP2.iterrows():
    TEMP3 = TEMP3.append(FULL.loc[FULL['Mgr Email Address']==row["Email 
Address"]])
SMITH_STAFF = SMITH_STAFF.append(TEMP3)
```

I expect the smith staff file to contain the employee and manager email addresses for all employees that ultimately report up to JohnSmith.  In this example, that would be employee1, employee2, and employee3

Comment: Is the leader at the top level or might they also have a manager? If top level, a (fairly efficient?) recursive function could get the top-level leader for each employee. Then it would be a simple selection.

Comment: Rather than iterating, you might be able to find a simpler solution with groupby and list, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: Is your 'Example:' for the FULL dataframe supposed to be formatted? I can't follow it.

Comment: I can't vouch for it, but some quick googling turned up the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521390/getting-all-descendants-of-a-parent-from-a-pandas-dataframe-parent-child-table

Comment: They also have a manager.  The manager is listed for each employee, which means I need to be able to trace the managers up to the right leader.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the groupby and getting the descendents from a parent.  My search terms weren't that great I guess.  I'll check it out.

Comment: This routine worked perfectly: stackoverflow.com/questions/46521390/